# Подключиться к Access на php

Tags: php, unix, access, odbc

Имеется сайт на PHP+MySql, unix-хостинг. Есть необходимость подключения к файлам БД Access предварительно загруженных по ФТП в папку сайта. Пробовал подключаться через odbc, работает только локально. На хостинге с включенным php расширением odbc не работает. Строка подключения odbc_connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver
(*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=db_name.mdb;Uid=;Pwd=;',"",""). Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: дак и `Microsoft Access Driver` то установлен? если таковые вообще существуют

Comment: На сервере подключено расширение odbc. Техподдержка ответила: "На хостинге не установлен Access и установить не предоставляется технически возможно потому что Access это технология от Microsoft а наш хостинг не работает под управлением Windows. 
Разве что только если Вы удаленно с нашего хостинга подключитесь к Access базе но она должна быть доступна из Интернета."

Comment: ну для того чтобы работать с access устанавливать его не требуется. По крайней мере для баз в формате accdb, по крайней мере под винду существуют драйвера Access db engine. Есть ли они под никсы я хз. Одбс даст вам интерфейсы подключения и апи для работы, а непосредственно работу с файлами все равно проводит драйвер, и он нужен. Конечно, на сторонний хостинг никто вам его ставить не будет, разве что он у вас выделенный  и вы сами можете что-то устанавливать.